# How do I re-inject specific object with Dagger

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

In my app I have two modes: demo and real. In demo mode I mock server communication by using another class:

```
@Module(...)
public class CommunicationModule {
    @Provides @Singleton CommunicationWrapper provideNetworkBusWrapper(Application app) {
        boolean isDebug = ((MyApplication) app).isDebug();

        CommunicationWrapper result = null;

        if (isDebug) {
            result = new DemoWrapper(app);
        } else {
            result = new NetworkWrapper(app);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now after a specific user action I'd like to reinitialize this dependency. Is it it possible to do it without rebuilding the whole `ObjectGraph`?

Answer (score 2):

You can re-inject the object so the implementation will be changed based on your flag. Just remove the `@Singleton` annotation from your provide method.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

   @Inject CommunicationWrapper mCommunicationWrapper;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ((MyApplication) getApplication()).inject(this);
      // using NetworkWrapper
      ...
   }

   public void userActionHandler(){
      ((MyApplication) getApplication()).setDebug(true);
      ((MyApplication) getApplication()).inject(this);
      // using DemoWrapper
      ...
}
```

Remember that all your dependencies of the class will be re-injected.

Comment: The problem is that I want to share CommunicationWrapper  instance between multiple objects. So I need it to be Singleton

Comment: Why not keep a single instance of `DemoWrapper` and `NetworkWrapper` in your module? I think you demand too much from a DI library. If you need something that's not common you have to implement this on your own (like returning singleton instead of using `@Singleton`).

Comment: How can we decide that we require a NetworkWrapper or DemoWrapper instance on same code where we call inject().

Answer (score 1):

*This comment treats about Dagger 1*

I am not realy sure if it will help you but have you analysed [U2020 app created by Jake Wharton as example of using Dagger](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020)? 
Based on my analyse he adds two graphs in debug mode (standard module and debug module). Debug module can override functionalities of standard module (on runtime), but I haven't found where exactly it implemented. In this app it's provided by button in menu - maybe you will find it faster (I have some problems with gradle)

Comment: In that app he just rebuilds the whole object graph. I thought threre's another way around.

Comment: Well, as I understand, it isn't true - he builds bigger graph for debug mode and reinject mock implementation of ApplicationContainer (DebugAppContainer) for Mock Mode. In my opinion it isn't rebuilding graph. Yes, Activity is destroyed but graph is still the same.

Comment: Debugging it is much more harder than I thought. You have right - even in logs I can observer 'buildObjectGraphAndInject()' notification, everytime when I've changed 'Endpoint'

Answer (score 1):

To have 2 versions that you include conditionally, but want to swap out on some other changing condition, you could provide the 2 types from singletons, and then provide to your dependency from the without the singleton.

```
// DemoWrapper.java
@Singleton // Alternatively, you could add provides methods for the wrapper types and annotate those with @Singleton
class DemoWrapper { ... }

// NetworkWrapper.java
@Singleton
class NetworkWrapper { ... }

// CommunicationModule.java
@Module(
    ...,
    injects = {
        DemoWrapper.class,
        NetworkWrapper.class
    }
)
public class CommunicationModule {

    @Provides
    CommunicationWrapper provideNetworkBusWrapper(Application app, DemoWrapper demo, NetworkWrapper network) {
        boolean isDebug = ((MyApplication) app).isDebug();

        return isDebug ? demo : network;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe both test and debug build variants will return true in isDebug();

Comment: Your condition to switch between the two could be whatever you like. A shared preference, application debug mode, or `BuildConfig.Flavor`.